# Why is Femme Fatale so expensive to install?

Tags: android-netrunner

Femme fatale costs 9 to install and I am struggling to figure out why it costs so much. The card has the ability to render a piece of ice fairly useless by allowing you to break its subroutines by paying one coin. However, I can also do that with other, cheaper, better icebreakers. I am just a little confused on why it costs 9.

Comment: As a general comment, Killers (i.e. Sentry breakers) are universally fairly expensive/inefficient. That's a fairly common design feature of these programs.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly I think that ability is just the answer. It's a decent sentry icebreaker (filling a slot, albeit at a high cost), but a great counter to ice like [these](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=t:ICE%20p%3E5%20d:c). Just imagine Corp plays a Wotan, and suddenly you bust out a Femme Fatale. Anyway, you probably don't want to use FF anyway without some sort of ability to help you install it cheaper. :)

[image: Femme Fatale card image]
[image]

Comment: I think Andrew is correct.  It is multi-purpose as a decent general Sentry breaker, but - when targeted - becomes an excellent breaker for extremely hard to get through ICE.  As Andrew mentions, there are also ways of installing it for less credits (e.g. modded), AND there are ways of retargeting it for free (e.g. scavenge).  So, even if the ICE you originally target loses its appeal (maybe by mid-game you are no longer interested in running R&D or something), paired with a few other cards, it remains useful.

Comment: One other comment: You should note that Femme "bypasses" subroutines, it does not "break" them. So, some card effects can still hurt you - even if you use Femme to prevent all the subroutines (e.g. Chum will hit you for 3 net damage if you use Femme)

Comment: Oh, great point. I did not realize that about "bypass". :) Skeptical, I tried to find a way to refute you, but in fact FF says "When you encounter...", while Chum says "The next piece of ice the runner encounters...". So you are totally correct. Interesting stuff!

Comment: So when it says bypass...does that mean regardless of strength I only need to pay for the subroutines?

Comment: For Femme?  Yes.  But she only works on the particular ICE you chose when she hit the table.  So, if you play Femme on Wotan (as shown above), you can spend 4 credits to bypass all of its subroutines - even though a) she is not a fracter (and so, normally, wouldn't be able to help with barrier ICE) and b) she does not have strength 10.

Comment: Femme is also great for avoiding ICE that have effects outside of subroutines, like [Tollbooth](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01090). Being able to avoid that kind of ICE _entirely_ is pretty valuable.